# Python solve ODE

Tags: python

How to solve a ODE，I have tried to use scipy.integrate.odeint, but what should I do if I don't know the initial value，

[image]

That's what I've defined：

```
alpha=0.204
beta=0.196
b=5.853
c=241.38

def Left_equation(x):
   return alpha * x

def Right_equation(x):
   return (b * (x ** 2)) + c

def diff_equation(x, t):
   return (t ** beta) * (Right_equation(x) - Left_equation(x))
```

I also want to get the graph of the result,I don't know if I need to get the analytic solution first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the initial condition is not known, then the integration would need to be done symbolically. The Python package [`sympy`](https://www.sympy.org) can be used for symbolic integration of [ordinary differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation), as follows (using the function [`sympy.dsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/ode.html#dsolve)):

```py
"""How to integrate symbolically an ordinary differential equation."""
import sympy


def main():
    alpha = 0.204
    beta = 0.196
    b = 5.853
    c = 241.38
    t = sympy.symbols('t')
    x = sympy.Function('x')(t)
    dxdt = sympy.Derivative(x, t)
    e = (t**beta) * ((b * (x**2)) + c - alpha * x)
    x_eq = sympy.dsolve(dxdt - e)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For this example, the function `sympy.solvers.ode.ode.dsolve` raises the exception [`PolynomialDivisionFailed`](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/8ddf9c29e345df987e82f8c5905dd0b32ea0a4b6/sympy/polys/polyerrors.py#L31). But the above code shows how to do symbolic integration.

An alternative is to numerically solve the differential equation (for specific initial condition), and compute solutions for a range of initial conditions, to explore how the solution depends on the initial condition. Using the function [`scipy.integrate.odepack.odeint`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) of the Python package [`scipy`](https://www.scipy.org), and the Python packages [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org) and [`numpy`](https://numpy.org), this can be done as follows:

```py
"""How to integrate numerically an ordinary differential equation."""
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate


def main():
    x0 = np.linspace(0, 0.2, 10)  # multiple alternative initial conditions
    t = np.linspace(0, 0.01, 100)  # where to solve
    x = scipy.integrate.odeint(deriv, x0, t)
    # plot results
    plt.plot(t, x)
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.ylabel('x')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


def deriv(x, t):
    alpha = 0.204
    beta = 0.196
    b = 5.853
    c = 241.38
    return (t ** beta) * ((b * (x**2)) + c - alpha * x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As noted though in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html) of the function `scipy.integrate.odeint`:

> For new code, use [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html#scipy.integrate.solve_ivp) to solve a differential equation.

The function [`scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) can be used as follows:

```py
"""How to integrate numerically an ordinary differential equation."""
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate


def main():
    x0 = np.linspace(0, 0.2, 10)  # multiple alternative initial conditions
    t = (0.0, 0.01)  # where to solve: (start, end)
    res = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp(deriv, t, x0)  # different order of
        # arguments than for the function `scipy.integrate.odeint`
    # plot results
    plt.plot(res.t, res.y.T)
    plt.xlabel('t')
    plt.ylabel('x')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()


def deriv(t, x):  # not x, t as for the function `scipy.integrate.odeint`
    alpha = 0.204
    beta = 0.196
    b = 5.853
    c = 241.38
    return (t ** beta) * ((b * (x**2)) + c - alpha * x)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Please note the differences in arguments between the function `scipy.integrate.odeint` and the function `scipy.integrate.solve_ivp`.

The above code produces the following plot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for helping, and can you explain why set the x0(initial conditions), between 0 to 0.2, and "t" to solve from 0.0 to 0.01? Is this arbitrary?

Comment: The reason for this choice of initial conditions was because with other values (e.g., larger time interval), the solution appears to diverge very quickly over `t`: I observed `x` values in the order of `10**12`, and then becoming 0 for larger values of `t`. So I tried to find some areas of values for `t` an `x` such that a solution can be obtained without numerical instability.